# Adding DIV with a close button, dynamically to another DIV  using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to add 4 divs with close buttons on top right corner , aligned horizontally to a parent DIV.
When the close button is clicked, the div should be removed from the parent DIV. Is this possible with Jquery ?if someone could post a sample code i would really appreciate it !

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible ,create a sample code yourself and ask for help when some error comes up or specific problem comes up. http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's help you.

<kbd>**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uvabux/edit#javascript,html,live)**</kbd>

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="close_box">X</div>

    <h2>Box title</h2>
    <p>Merol muspi rolod tis tema...</p>

</div>
```

jQ:

```
$(document).on('click','.close_box',function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeTo(300,0,function(){
          $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

or simply:

```
$(document).on('click','.close_box',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Take a look at the docs (**always!**):

http://api.jquery.com/on/
http://api.jquery.com/parent/
http://api.jquery.com/remove

Comment: Thanks !  i tried the code in Jsfiddle.net and when i clicked the close X,the div is nor removed.I think i am  doing something wrong.http://jsfiddle.net/tYHmN/

Comment: @user636525 you just forgot to call jQuery (in the left **"Choose framework"** tab) http://jsfiddle.net/tYHmN/1/ Otherwise it works, great job. P.S. go to my demo in my answer, go to **save->download** and you can play locally!

Comment: Thank you ! I am a .Net developer, very new to Jquery, i will be looking for your help more often :)

Comment: @user636525 You're really welcome! Thanks... glad I could help. P.S. but in the future add a code snip into your questions, or you might end downvoted! Happy coding