# "x" delete field from dynamic form

Tags: jquery, tags

I would like to add and delete fields dynamically in a form as following: 
 [image]

here is my code: 
JQuery

```
$('#addFeild').click(function(){
    $('#divTest').append("<div> <input name='titres' type='text'/> <a href='#' id='close_box'>x</a>  </div>");
});

$('#close_box').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Jsp:

```
<html:form action="/test.do">
    <div id="divTest">
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="addFeild">+</a> 
    <html:submit property="submit" value="Submit"/>
</html:form>
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596164/adding-div-with-a-close-button-dynamically-to-another-div-using-jquery) example but it doesn't work!!
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called `event delegation` issues, whenever an event is bound to a dynamically generated element then that event needs to be delegated to the closest static parent like:

```
$('#divTest').on('click', '#close_box', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

and instead of `.parent()` you can use `.closest()` too:

```
$(this).closest('div').remove();
```

---

The syntax of `event delegation` is like:

```
$(staticparent).on(event, selector, callback);
```

---

### Note:

if you are not delegating to closest static parent then you don't need to have to put the bound event in `doc ready` block.

As this answer is suggesting to use the closest static parent then **you have to put the event in the doc ready block**.

so try this:

```
$(function(){ // doc ready
   $('#divTest').on('click', '#close_box', function(){
       $(this).parent().remove();
   });
}); // doc ready ends
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, but its still not working which is weird!

Comment: Would you explain not working? i mean is there any error in the console after clicking the `x` button.

Comment: Okay! do you have unique ids right, i mean there is no element on the page with same id `close_box` not even a hidden one.

Comment: actually I changed the browser here is what I found as error: TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

Comment: Oh! what is the version of your jQuery? `.on()` method needs `jQuery 1.7+` better to use the latest build of it.

Comment: That is why it is not working? As you are using `1.4` then you can use `.live()` _but use of it not recommended_

Comment: _changed it_...to what version?

Comment: Changed it to 1.11.
I'm going to test it online!

Comment: I tested it online it worked so the problem is somewhere else, thanks for your help, I'll figure it out

Comment: Sorry, I just thought I can mark the both as an answer, cuz the guy above gave a good answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

That example clearly shows [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to be implemented and you haven't done that!

So Try this:

```
$("#divTest").on('click','#close_box',function(){
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

But i suggest you to create unique IDs for the close boxes, as IDs must be unique or either use a class instead of an ID

```
$('#divTest').append("<div> <input name='titres' type='text'/> <a href='#' class="close_box">x</a>  </div>");


$("#divTest").on('click','.close_box',function(){  // with class 
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

Comment: I dunno what's the problem I'm still testing, it's not working!

Comment: Its not showing any error. Which part did u update?!

Comment: @ABDOZeidane I have update the way you removing your parent div, used `$(this).closest('div').remove()` instead `$(this).parent().remove()`

Comment: It still not working, I've already tried that one its in the answer down!

Answer (score 1):

use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** .

- Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
  parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
  selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
  future.

---

```
 $("#divTest").on("click","#close_box",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the brief details, the same answer above is not working!

Comment: @ABDOZeidane please show us the rendered html.. there may be chance of problem in the selector..!

Answer (score 0):

when you dynamically add an element you should put an event listener to it if you want it to be triggered on an event:

```
$(document).on('click','#close_box',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
$('#close_box').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```